# Mac - List All Image Paths (Names) in a Directory and Its Subdirectories

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I like to list all image names in a directory with its subdirectories using terminal on Mac. I used the below command, it listed everything including folder names, but not working for my problem.

```
ls -R /Users/samuel/Apps/assets/images > file_names.txt
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact extension of what constitutes an "image" file, then use this example below for jpg files:

```
ls -R /Users/samuel/Apps/assets/images  | grep "*.jpg" > file_names.txt
```

For a broader definition of "image" file try this:

```
mdfind image -onlyin /Users/samuel/Apps/assets/images > file_names.txt
```

The first has to be run for each known image type. The second one may include any file with "image" in its metadata.

Comment: Not sure how it was in 2015, but thanks for pointing out mdfind at least!
The man page of mdfind says you can use finder search commands, so perhaps someone might wanna try `mdfind kind:image -onlyin ...`